# GAE + Django, upload big files

Tags: django, google-app-engine, file-upload

I use GAE + Django 1.3 + Cloud SQL.

I've never coded on GAE before, but I need to deploy a completed project that was written in Django. For working with files in Django models (`FileField`, `ImageField`) I use https://github.com/fhahn/django-gae-blobstorage.

There is one problem: the custom editors (and Django admin too) can't load files larger than ~ 30MB. Quick search showed that it is necessary to use Blobstore (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview).

Everything seems simple enough, but it is impossible to reconcile Blobstore with Django model.

I found http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-rocket-engine. it has the ideas to solve this problem, but the result is the same: `413 Request Entity Too Large`.

P.S. I must use GAE, so changing the hosting provider is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

django-rocket-engine is using memory based upload, so you can try with this setting inside django settings.py
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#file-upload-max-memory-size

Answer (score 0):

[django-filetransfers](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers) should allow you to target App Engine blobstore for application file upload.